# Browser X axis scrollbar is shown but its disabled

Tags: css, responsive-design

I put an `overflow-x: scroll` on the body tag, yet the scrollbar is disabled.

I dont understand why?

I tried to put min width on it too but that did not work either.

Comment: Do you have any content in it that is wider than the viewport? if you don't have. the scroll bars will be disabled like this https://jsfiddle.net/0d3e4pee/ , but if you have content https://jsfiddle.net/0d3e4pee/1/

Answer (score 0):

Setting `overflow` to `scroll` will typically make the [scrollbar always visible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).

You may want to use `auto` instead of `scroll`.